# issue in search and display the report

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

views.py

```
def search(request):
    """"""" 
    if 'search' in request.POST:
                search_keyword = request.POST.get('search_keyword')
                reports = reports.filter(Q(incident_description__icontains=search_keyword) | Q(incident_number__icontains=search_keyword) | Q(reportperson__name__icontains=search_keyword))    
    """""""
    return render(request,'search.html',{'searchform':searchform})
```

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    incident_number = models.CharField('Incident Number', max_length=100)
    incident_description = models.TextField('Incident description', null=True, blank=True)

class ReportPerson(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    action_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ACTION_TYPE)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
```

The above view perform the keyword search(search on data in the model field) from Report model and Reportperson model.

A report stored in Report model can have more than 2 reportperson details.

In database the values would be like this,

If the values in Report table and Reportperson table are as in the image,Report model is

[image: Report model]

reportperson model is

[image: reportperson model]

Here,a report is having two reportperson detail.If i perform search with this case,the same report is displayed two times.Depence on the number of reportperson detail,the count of showing the same report showing again and again varies.

I want to know how to handle this,this is happening because i am using name search from Reportperson table.Problem is happening from this `report=reports.filter(....| Q(reportperson__name__icontains=search_keyword))`,.Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a SELECT DISTINCT ? (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)